# What is the difference drawableStart and drawableLeft?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I want to add logo to button , if I add with drawableLeft its working but when I add with drawableStart its not working. What's difference between drawableLeft and drawableStart?

Comment: What type of button? ImageButton, Button, MaterialButton?

Answer (score 1):

`drawableStart` and `drawableEnd` only start switching sides when you [enable RTL support](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html) in API Level 17 and above. `RTL Support` basically means support for bidirectional text in `TextView` and `EditText` elements, allowing apps to display and edit text in both left-to-right (LTR) and right-to-left (RTL) scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
app:icon="@drawable/your_file"
```

You can use this. RTL works fine for me